# About bluetooth socket issue

Tags: android, performance, android-bluetooth

I am working on the android application of RFID/NFC reader with bluetooth connection. Once the application is working fine. But there is a problem with subsequent opening of this application. How to overcome this BluetoothSocket Problem.
While onDestroy called, I close the bluetooth socket and also disable the bluetooth. But after then launch application again it will give following error.
If I wait for 10-15sec. then launch the application, it will work fine. So how to overcome this issue with bluetooth socket

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.available()' on a null object reference
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.available(BluetoothSocket.java:488)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.available(BluetoothInputStream.java:40)
            at com.bonrix.nfc.bluetooth.rfiddemo.TagId.dsrcvdata(TagId.java:302)
            at com.bonrix.nfc.bluetooth.rfiddemo.TagId.access$100(TagId.java:39)
            at com.bonrix.nfc.bluetooth.rfiddemo.TagId$myrunnablethread.run(TagId.java:265)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Once closing application and immediately opened again it will give above error. But after 10-15sec. again launch the application, it will work fine. So, what's the issue? and how to overcome this issue in android?

Comment: It seems you are not referencing your bluetooth object when the activity lifecycle starts.

Comment: I am referencing  bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bluetoothAdapter.enable(); in onCreate method. App run fine after the break between 10sec. But After finishing and then launch immediately invite the crash.

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is that when you first quit from the app, android caches the app for a short time to start it faster.Meaning your app is not ended actually but after a short time. I think you are loosing the reference in that point.

Comment: As you said problem of caches, so what should I do to avoid this?

Comment: Can you try using `bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();` in `onResume()`?

Comment: Still the app crashes because of the nullpointerexception.